# Restore vs recovery in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working on a project which needs me to take backup and restore Postgres instances quite frequently. While going through the official Postgres documentation, I came to know about recovery.conf file also. Apparently its only used when the database crashes.

My question is how exactly is it determined about whether or not the database needs recovery in real time? For example, when restoring a Postgres instance backed up earlier, sometimes I see that the data restore is complete but the instance could not start for different reasons. Is such a scenario supposed to be a crash ? When exactly does Postgres take matters into its own hands and decides to perform a recovery instead of a restore?

Regards
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Crash recovery is automatically performed after a crash.

Archive recovery is run by the DBA and involves `recovery.conf`. You use it to restore an old state of the database.